# Navigating JSON path

Tags: json, delphi

I am attempting to parse a JSON response using a `TRestResponse`. Unfortunately my understanding of JSON is letting me down.

For instance, given the following JSON:

```json
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "description": "Eiffel Tower",
                    "score": 0.714323,
                    "boundingVals": {
                        "vertices": [
                            {
                                "x": 213,
                                "y": 813
                            },
                            {
                                "x": 332,
                                "y": 813
                            },
                            {
                                "x": 332,
                                "y": 2183
                            },
                            {
                                "x": 213,
                                "y": 2183
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "latLng": {
                                "latitude": 48.858461,
                                "longitude": 2.294351
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    ]
}
```

I can retrieve the first `x` value using this:

```pascal
rstResponse.RootElement := 'responses[0].annotations[0].boundingVals.vertices';
x := VarToStr(MemTable.FieldValues['x']).ToInteger;
```

But I **cannot** retrieve the latitude using this:

```pascal
rstResponse.RootElement := 'responses[0].annotations[0].locations.latLng';
lat  := VarToStr(FDMemTable.FieldValues['latitude']);
```

The first line returns an error:

> Response RootElement, "responses[0].annotations[0].locations.latLng", is not a valid path for the Response JSON

I can use this:

```pascal
rstResponse.RootElement := 'responses[0].annotations[0].locations';
s := VarToStr(FDMemTable.FieldValues['latLng']);
```

But then `s` is obviously `{ "latitude": 48.858461, "longitude": 2.294351 }`, which I would need to parse myself.

Can you please highlight what is wrong with `'responses[0].annotations[0].locations.latLng'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`locations` is an array of objects, but you are not indexing into it, like you are with the other arrays. Try this instead:

```
rstResponse.RootElement := 'responses[0].annotations[0].locations[0].latLng';`
```

Comment: Sorry, of course, you are right. I thought I had checked and dismissed that. Thanks Remy